# How to find intersection points between lines and contours

Tags: python, opencv, contour

Consider the below image where contours is shown in green and straight lines are shown in red

[image]

how can we find point of intersections where straight lines cuts contours

```
import cv2 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Read image img

# Binarize
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
_,thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Find Contours
_, contours, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Draw Contours
blank_mask = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0],thresh.shape[1],3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(blank_mask, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1) 

# Define lines coordinates
line1 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
line2 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
line3 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]

# Draw Lines over Contours
cv2.line(blank_mask, (line1[0], line1[1]), (line1[2], line1[3]), (255, 0, 0), thickness=1)
cv2.line(blank_mask, (line2[0], line2[1]), (line2[2], line2[3]), (255, 0, 0), thickness=1)
cv2.line(blank_mask, (line3[0], line3[1]), (line3[2], line3[3]), (255, 0, 0), thickness=1)

# Show Image
fig = plt.figure()
ax  = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(blank_mask)
```

[Sample Image](https://i.postimg.cc/nVwY7w7b/download-1.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check pixel by pixel to see where they overlap. You have to keep a copy of the pixels where the contours are before drawing the lines, because that will overwrite the overlapping pixels with the colour of the line. Add a couple of lines in your code here

```
# Draw Contours
blank_mask = np.zeros((thresh.shape[0],thresh.shape[1],3), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(blank_mask, contours, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)
contours_idx = blank_mask[...,1] == 255

# Define lines coordinates
line1 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
line2 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]
line3 = [x1, y1, x2, y2]

# Draw Lines over Contours
cv2.line(blank_mask, (line1[0], line1[1]), (line1[2], line1[3]), (255, 0, 0), thickness=1)
cv2.line(blank_mask, (line2[0], line2[1]), (line2[2], line2[3]), (255, 0, 0), thickness=1)
cv2.line(blank_mask, (line3[0], line3[1]), (line3[2], line3[3]), (255, 0, 0), thickness=1)
lines_idx = blank_mask[...,0] == 255
```

And then

```
overlap = np.where(contours_idx * lines_idx)
```

Which will give you something similar to the following (I had to guess your line coordinates and image resize shape, so I may be a bit off)

```
(array([ 90, 110, 110, 140, 140], dtype=int64), array([ 80,  40, 141,  27, 156], dtype=int64))
```

And if you want them in tuples of pixel coordinates

```
list(zip(*overlap))
```

---

**Edit**: For a more general solution where the colour of the contours/lines is in more than one plane, you can check for the full colour of each pixel after each draw. For example

```
# Change these
contours_idx = blank_mask[...,1] == 255
lines_idx = blank_mask[...,0] == 255

# To this
contours_idx = np.all(blank_mask == (0, 255, 0), axis=-1)
lines_idx = np.all(blank_mask == (255, 0, 0), axis=-1)
```